# Skip debugging of copy constructors of function's input parameters?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

When one steps into the debug function with multiple input parameters, it is a quite a time waster to enter and leave a copy constructor of each input parameter. Most often than not, these copy constructors are trivial (increase the reference counter), and what a developer really want is to "step right into *function*", and skip debugging through of input parameters creation, 
be it a call to a copy ctor, or a call to a function which creates the instance of parameter object.

**Is there a way in a Visual Studio to configure the debugging in a such way, as to avoid the debugging of the construction/copy construction 
of the parameters and to go right to the function's body?**

Comment: Not sure if there's a way besides putting a breakpoint in the function you actually want to stop in, but doing "Step In" then "Step out" again will get you to the 'next' part of calling the function, eventually you'll get into the function itself.

Answer (score 4):

alt-shift-F11 in Visual Studio 10 or higher brings up a list of all the functions that will be called and you can select the function you would like to go directly to. I find this incredibly useful, but unsure if you are using VS10 or an earlier version.

Comment: Kyle refers to Debug.StepIntoSpecific feature